# Django Forms with a field based on a Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a Django Form that add new instances of a Model. The Model itself have a ForeignKey instance. Let's say I wanna record all work shifts of each worker.

My Model:

```
class WorkShifts(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    check_in = models.TimeField()
    check_out = models.TimeField()
    person_name = models.ForeignKey(Worker, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

And this is my Form:

```
class AddWorkShifts(forms.ModelForm):

    date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today, input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])
    check_in = forms.TimeField()
    check_out = forms.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = WorkShifts
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(AddWorkShifts, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['date'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['check_in'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['check_out'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['person_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

My HTML code:

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}


      {{ form.date }}<br />
      {{ form.check_in }}<br />
      {{ form.check_out }}<br />
      {{ form.person_name }}

      <button type="submit">Load</button>

  </form>
```

And my view:

```
def load_shifts(request):
    form = AddWorkShifts()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddWorkShifts(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/wshifts.html', context)
```

At this point, everything works fine. Notice that form.is_valid doesnt have the () signs.

But since I have so many persons (the Foreign Key), I configured a JS Autocomplete plugin (EaseAutoComplete) and redesign the form like this:

```
      <form align="center" method="POST">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="text" class="p_name" id="provider-file" />

          {{ form.date }}<br />
          {{ form.check_in }}<br />
          {{ form.check_out }}<br />

          <button type="submit">Agregar</button>

      </form>
```

The autocomplete suggestions are taken from a json list. But while the autocomplete function works fine, **now I can't create new instances.**

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The statement **`form.is_valid`** (without parenthesis) doesn't make any sense. **`is_valid()`** is a function and you should have called it in the first place.

Comment: Great. Thanks Arakkal. But anyway, what I need is to get the text input value like if was form.person_name.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not sending `person_name` which is required by form. You need to use the `name` attribute in the input field to provide the value to the form.

`<input type="text" class="p_name" id="provider-file" name="person_name" />`